# How to implement a map for array of strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

My code :

```
var appsAndScopes=[
['1',['A','B','C','D']],
['2 ',['E','F','G','H']],
['3',['I']],
['4',['J']]
];
function getAllElements(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
  function buildDropdowns(){
    var applications=getAllElements('application').options;  //Gets all applications names from appsAndScopes array.
    for(var applicationsIndex=0;applicationsIndex<appsAndScopes.length;applicationsIndex++){
      applications[applications.length]=new Option(appsAndScopes[applicationsIndex][0],appsAndScopes[applicationsIndex][0]);
    }

    getAllElements('application').onchange=function(){
      this.blur();
      var currentApplication=this.value;
      if(!currentApplication){return;}
      var scopes=getAllElements('scope').options;
      scopes.length=1;
      for(var scopesIndex=0;scopesIndex<appsAndScopes.length;scopesIndex++){
        if(appsAndScopes[scopesIndex][0]!==currentApplication){continue;}
        else{
          var temp=appsAndScopes[scopesIndex][1];
          for(var valueIndex=0;valueIndex<temp.length;valueIndex++){
            scopes[scopes.length]=new Option(temp[valueIndex],temp[valueIndex]);
          }
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  $(function() {
      buildDropdowns();
  });
```

In this code, I am generating dynamic drop downs (i.e. dependent drop downs). This code is working fine. It's using 2d array to populate the values of drop downs. I want to implement a map instead of 2d array. That will change the whole process of iterating also.

I am very new to javascript. I don't know any of the syntax for javascript. Please help me doing that.

Comment: You don't seem to accept solutions. You get repo points too when you accept the solutions. Not accepting the solutions would not encourage people to help you!

Answer (score 0):

declare a map object

```
var map = new Map(); // or var map = {};
```

inserting a new item

```
map.set(key, value);
```

in your case you can use like `map.set(1,['a','b','c','d']);`
retrieving a item

```
map.get(key); // will return value
```

for more detailed uses see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map